# How to get header to shrink and stay shrunk until back at the top?

Tags: javascript, html, css, wordpress, header

I am trying to get my header like this:
http://commonreads.com/

Where when you scroll it shrinks and it only becomes full again when you return to the top.
Currently, with my code it is shrinking but then unshrinking upon scrolling up. ( rather than staying hidden till top )

My code is thus:

```
<script>

jQuery(function($){
   
var topPosition = 0;
 
 
$(window).scroll(function() {
 
    var scrollMovement = $(window).scrollTop();
   
    if (topPosition < 100 ){
    }
    else{
    if(scrollMovement > topPosition) {
          $('#global-header-section').removeClass('show-header');
          $('#global-header-section').addClass('hide-header');
    } else {
          $('#global-header-section').removeClass('hide-header');
          $('#global-header-section').addClass('show-header');
    }
    }
    topPosition = scrollMovement;
});  
   
});
  
  </script>

<style>

#main-content{
margin-top: 7vw;
}
 
.hide-header {
opacity: 1;
margin-top: -11.5vw !important;
}
 
.show-header {
opacity: 1;
margin-top: 0px !important;
}
 
#global-header-section {
-webkit-transition: all 0.5s ease !important;
-moz-transition: all 0.5s ease !important;
-o-transition: all 0.5s ease !important;
-ms-transition: all 0.5s ease !important;
transition: all 0.5s ease !important;
}

</style>
```

Here it is live:
https://callum.mavendd.com/maven-services/

Hopefully, that makes sense.

Thank you!

Comment: I recommend you read this: https://www.w3schools.com/howto/howto_js_navbar_shrink_scroll.asp

Comment: I'm not sure if that is the same because mine isn't technically "shrinking" it is sliding up to hide a portion and then sliding back down using margin-top

Comment: You can use this jQuery plugin to achieve this : https://www.jqueryscript.net/menu/Shrink-Nav-On-Scroll-jQuery-CSS3.html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use such function for detecting scroll position

```
$(window).scroll(function(){
    if($(window).scrollTop()>100){
        //do something when scroll is greater than 100 from top
    } else {
        //do something else
    }
});
```